# Using Shopify API Python, add new product with price and 'requires_shipping': False

Tags: python, api, shopify, variants

I am trying to add a new product through the Python Shopify API. I know how to add title and body and a picture but I am having issues with adding price and I need to have 'requires_shipping': False. I can't find anywhere how to achieve this.

This is what I have so far.

```
import shopify    
API_KEY = 'dsfsdsdsdsdsad'
PASSWORD = 'sadsdasdasdas'

shop_url = "https://%s:%s@teststore.myshopify.com/admin" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)



path = "audi.jpg"

new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "Audi pictures test "
new_product.body_html = "body of the page <br/><br/> test <br/> test"

###########this part is so far good. but the bottom part is not working#### 

variant = shopify.Variant(price=9.99)) # this does not work
new_product.variant() # this does not work
variant_2 = shopify.Variant(requires_shipping=False) #this does not work
new_product.variant_2() This does not work 



image = shopify.Image()

with open(path, "rb") as f:
    filename = path.split("/")[-1:][0]
    encoded = f.read()
    image.attach_image(encoded, filename=filename)

new_product.images = [image] # Here's the change
new_product.save()
```

Answer (score 5):

Only prefix options (e.g. `product_id` for Variants, `order_id` for Fulfillments) should be passed as explicit parameters to the constructor. If you want to initialize the attributes of the resource you'll need to pass them in as a dict.

You're also not associating your new variant with your new product at any point.

This should help:

```
new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "Shopify Logo T-Shirt"
new_product.body_html = "<b>Test description</b>"
variant = shopify.Variant({'price': 9.99, 'requires_shipping': False})
new_product.variants = [variant]
new_product.save()
=> True
```

You can also specify the attributes of the resource after initializing, as you're already doing for the Product resource.

```
variant = shopify.Variant()
variant.price = 9.99
variant.requires_shipping = False
```

Another option would be to save the product first and initialize the variant by passing the `product_id` explicitly, e.g.

`shopify.Variant(product_id=1234567)`

Take a look at the [README](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/master/README.md) for more usage examples.

Comment: would you know how I can add more than one picture? I am only able to add 1 picture with the code I have. However, I am having a difficult time with adding more than 1 picture.